# Color scatterplot according to vector

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two vectors:

```
X=np.array(np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix('[3,3,3,8,5,2,4,6,3,8,2,0,4,1,8,9,9,8,7,2,2,9,8,7,1,2,7,7,4,3,2,6,9;7,5,1,5,3,9,5,7,10,7,8,2,3,1,6,7,8,8,3,8,8,9,4,9,4,7,5,0,8,6,10,2,9]'))


labels=np.array(np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix('[1,1,3,2,3,4,1,4,4,2,1,1,3,1,2,2,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,4,1,1,2,3,4,1,4,3,2]'))


#plot the data
plt.plot(X.T[:,0],X.T[:,1],'.'); 
plt.scatter(X.T[:,0],X.T[:,1],s=50,marker='o',c="b")
plt.title('Plot of our points');
```

[image]

I would like to produce a scatterplot, but color it according to the `labels` vector. How can I do this?

Comment: Your `scatter` command overplots on `plot` results - maybe remove the latter one.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, the problem was with reading my labels vector.

```
labels=np.array(np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix('[1,1,3,2,3,4,1,4,4,2,1,1,3,1,2,2,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,4,1,1,2,3,4,1,4,3,2]'))
```

I changed this to

```
labels=np.array([1,1,3,2,3,4,1,4,4,2,1,1,3,1,2,2,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,4,1,1,2,3,4,1,4,3,2])
```

and it basically solves the issue.

Comment: It would be helpful to accept this as the answer so others can know at a glance that the problem is solved.

Comment: it says i have to wait two days, will do once its over!

Answer (score 0):

Replace keyword: `c=labels`. See [scatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) for more info

Comment: I tried that, I get ```ValueError: c of shape (1, 33) not acceptable as a color sequence for x with size 33, y with size 33```

Comment: It works for me. Maybe try changing shape of `c` to `(33)`. It's best achieved by simplifying your code: `labels = np.array([1,1...])`. Other simple solution may be `c=labels.T`.